# Eclipse PDT does not underline syntax errors and code completion

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code Completion not working with remote file (with RSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896909/code-completion-not-working-with-remote-file-with-rse)

Ater installing Eclipse PDT on my Mac(snow leopard), I installed Remote System Explorer (RSE) from http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/updates/3.0/.

Now the editor neither underline syntax errors, nor do the code completion. But the editor does color the code. Where I can config it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

In found out on my own skin, that the best option in this case is just to remove the project from list in eclipse, then go to the location of your project and delete:

- .settings - directory
- .buildpath - file
- .project - file

After that just create a new PHP project and everything will start working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem, I found that it was only broken for one of my projects.  The other projects showed the syntax error underlining just fine.

Solution:  I had accidentally gone into Project; Properties; Java Build Path; Source tab; expanded my project; and under Excluded, I had listed my project.  I had meant to include it, but had excluded it by mistake.

So check your build path.

Comment: I am having the above stated problem too and this is not the issue.  My highlighting appears occasionally if I hover over or highlight the problem if I happen to know where it is.  But it doesn't show automatically so that it can be seen at a glance.  It's quite frustrating.