# Code Completion not working with remote file (with RSE)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rse

What is:

On Host machine:
Windows 7
Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 2

On guest machine:
Linux debian squeeze

I want to edit my remote project through SSH in Eclipse by using RSE. All is okay, I do so in Remote System Explorer perspective:

[image: screenshot1]

Then I go to PHP perspective. Right click on project->Configure->Add PHP Support. And press `Ctrl+Shift+Space` or `Ctrl+Space`. No completions (code assist) available.

[image: screenshot2]

Okay I'm found this bug (at 2008) and solution description (at 2009): [Bug 251496](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=251496). I did so:

> Here's my solution to the problem:
>   I just deleted the RemoteSystemsTempFiles project in the PHPExplorer View and
>   than recreated it as a PHP Project (New->PHP Project, ofcourse it has to be
>   named again RemoteSystemsTempFiles). This worked for me, now code completion is
>   ok, hope this helps.

[image: screenshot3]

It does not solve the problem. Because PHP Language library does not have Core API maybe...
Help. Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution! Just create a dummy project (`localhost` for example) and import Core API in this dummy project. `Right click on dummy project->Import...->General->File System-><path to workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.php.core\_language_>`. Then  `Right click on your project->Include Path->Configure Include Path...->Projects->Add...-><dummy project>`. That's all! Code completion is working now.

Comment: Or if you don't want to create a project, just go: Right click on your project->Include Path->Configure Include Path...->Libraries->Add Library->Configure->New...->Click the newly created->Add External Folder-><path to workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.php.core\_language_> Probably a bit less hacky, but it still feels messy. I wish there was a proper fix.

Answer (score 6):

#### Autocompletion for the PHP project (classes, functions...):

I found that adding the folowing lines to the .project did solve the autocompletion issue for the classes of the PHP project itself but did not work with native PHP functions:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
```

I found a way around it:

#### Autocompletion for the native PHP functions (print_r()...):

You have to go to your eclipse configuration folder and find the PHP language folder:

In my case: `C:\Program Files\EclipseSF2\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\276\1\.cp\Resources\language\php5.3`

Then you can:

- right click at the root of your eclipse project,
- then go to build path
- link source
- browse: and link to this folder...

This allows the autocompletion for native PHP function!

#### Autocompletion for the Symfony framework:

For people using the Symfony framework you can add to your .project file the following lines:

```
<buildCommand>
        <name>com.dubture.symfony.core.symfonyBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Comment: This is the best solution i found on the web! 10x alot man. Onlt with the first two rows <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>  evertyhing started working, not only the autocomplete in classes but also the native PHP functions. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

When using RemoteSystemExplorer, there is a hidden project "RemoteSystemExplorer" in your workspace.

Close eclipse first. I have edited the .project file there and added the line:

`<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>`

within the Tag <natures>. And added the file .buildpath with the following content:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<buildpath>

    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>

    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>

</buildpath>`

Starting eclipse and php autocompletion is working. I have done this workflow with "eclipse Kepler".

Comment: Worked perfect for me in Eclipse 5.2 (Mars).  It even auto-completes other remote PHP files I have open, but aren't part of any particular project.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you from almost four years later, this still works. Also using Eclipse Neon

Answer (score 2):

*Solution*:

1) Close **Eclipse**.

2) Go to project path.

3) Open "**.buildpath**" with text editor (gedit, VIM, notepad, etc).

4) Add next line after "**buildpath**" line:

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

**Example**:

*Before*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="library"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="public"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="application"/>
</buildpath>
```

*After*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="library"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="public"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="application"/>
</buildpath>
```

5) Save file and exit!

6) Open Eclipse.

7) WORK!